# Using jquery .scroll() and scrollTop() to get height within Div

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, scrolltop

I have a scrollable div and when scroll to 'almost' bottom then will alert something. (for infinite ajax scroll use)

So here is my code, the code is actually working but ONLY when I paste into Google Chrome console and run it. Not working when I test in 'real' scroll. Any idea?

```
$('.div').scroll(function(){
  if ($('.div').scrollTop() + $('.div').height() > $('.lists').height() - 50) {
    alert('abc');
  }
});
```

Comment: Seems like it works to me: http://jsfiddle.net/kUkHn/

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, It works in my console as well. Is there any affect if the div comes from an Ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ajax, `.scroll` will not affect the div because it won't find it because it doesn't exist.  Instead, delegate with `.on`:

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.div', function () {
```